# Can you create a custom AWS Kinesis error-output-type?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm using AWS Kinesis Firehose streams to ingest data, followed by a lambda function to do schema validation and data transformation before writing to S3 buckets. I've previously been setting the status of incorrect records to ProcessingFailed and writing those errors to `{stream_id}/errors/{timestamp}/processing-failed` folder, but that method writes an automatically generated error response:

```
{
    "attemptsMade": "1",
    "arrivalTimestamp": "timestamp",
    "errorCode": "Lambda.ProcessingFailedStatus",
    "errorMessage": "ProcessingFailed status set for record",
    "attemptEndingTimestamp": "timestamp",
    "rawData": "data example",
    "lambdaArn": "arn"
}
```

Is it possible to create a custom error-output-type, which would write to `{stream_id}/errors/{timestamp}/custom-error`, with a custom error message and fields that look more like this?

```
{
    "errorCode": "ValidationFailedStatus",
    "errorMessage": "Validation failed because 'state' was not present in data"
}
```

I'd imagine the alternative is to use dynamic partitioning.

Comment: Hello 
Did you find a solution about your issue ? 